# value pass in react component props as typescript types for other props

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-props

I'm trying to read `value` passed to the prop of my react component, and read it as type for other props in the same component

```js
const TestPage = () => {
  return (
    <Test
      tabs={[
        { label: "test-label", value: "test" },
        { label: "something-label", value: "something" },
      ]}
      value="" // this should strict to and get autocomplete of "test" | "something" 
    />
  );
};
```

I tried to use generic to read the value passed in `tabsProp` like this

```js
type Tab<T> = { label: string; value: T };

type TestComponentProps<T> = {
  tabs: Tab<T>[];
  value: Tab<T>["value"];
};

const TestComponent = <T,>({ tabs, value }: TestComponentProps<T>) => (
  <div>{JSON.stringify({ tabs, value })}</div>
);
```

But still does not work.

I made an update based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73269696/12720875 in here https://stackblitz.com/edit/next-typescript-2fy4ng?file=pages%2Ftest.tsx, this fixed the strictness and the autocomplete

but I got another problem where the value also being spread as props key

[image: value spread as prop]

Answer (score 0):

You can use another generic type:

```
type ArrayElement<A> = A extends readonly (infer T)[] ? T : never

const TestComponent = <T extends Array<Record<string, Values>>, Values extends string,>({ tabs, value }: {
    tabs: T,
    value: ArrayElement<T>['value']
}) => (
  <div>{JSON.stringify({ tabs, value })}</div>
);
```

Update:

```
type Tab<T extends string> = { label: string; value: T };

function TestComponent<T extends string> ({
  tabs,
  value,
}: {
  tabs: Array<Tab<T>>;
  value: T;
}) => <div>{JSON.stringify({ tabs, value })}</div>;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but in my case I need `tabs` strict to { label: string; value: T };

Comment: I follow your answer and updated it https://stackblitz.com/edit/next-typescript-2fy4ng?file=pages%2Ftest.tsx so that it strict to `label` and `value`. But I have last problem where the value also detected as props key

Comment: I updated my answer as well. Yes you are right about that issue. I'm not sure why that is happening but I think I've seen similar issues before. But if you write `TestComponent({tabs: [{label: 'Start', value: '0'}], value: '0' })`, the editor will not make those wrong suggestions that it would make when you try to render the component (JSX). It only suggest those keys if you use JSX and try to use autocomplete **after** `value`.

Comment: the updated makes the value doesn't strict to what was put in tabs. if I put `tabs={[label: "test", value: "test]}`

I still can put any value in value props without type check from typescript. The autocomplete is there . but it still accept other value